# Random 'System.Text.DecoderFallbackException' with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

After building a WinForms application using EF 6.0 with database first I get the following errors randomly on the first start of the application. Most of the time a restart of the application solves the problem.

> 'System.Text.DecoderFallbackException' in mscorlib.dll Die Bytes [E9]
>   im Index 5974 können nicht von der angegebenen Codepage in Unicode
>   übersetzt werden. (Bytes[E9] at index 5974 could not be translated
>   from given codepage to Unicode)
>
> 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll Ungültiges Zeichen in der
>   angegebenen Codierung. Zeile 5337, Position 50. (Invalid character in
>   giving codepage.Row 5337, Position 50)
>
> 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' in EntityFramework.dll
>   Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
>   DataAccess.AppName.AppName.ssdl(5337,50) : error 0005: Ungültiges
>   Zeichen in der angegebenen Codierung. Zeile 5337, Position 50.
>   (Invalid character in giving codepage.Row 5337, Position 50)

It happens only but not always on the first start of the application. There seems to be no logic behind the error. I can do 20 builds without getting those exception and some days I just do one and the application shows those error Messages and has to be restarted because the metadata for EF is not loaded.

I checked the the `AppName.ssdl` file in the obj-Folder at the giving position:

```
<AssociationSet Name="FK_Folio_EST_Schaetzperioden" Association="Self.FK_Folio_EST_Schaetzperioden">
```

There is no unusual character in the line. Position 50 is an `r`.

The application is built on `framework 4.51, x86, EF 6.1.3`.

I was able to track the issue down to

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderResource.LoadResource
```

which uses GetManifestResourceStream.

This results in
[image: Encodeing error]

intermittently.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is cause by ClickShare version 01.00.04.0003.